# Command to visit Github pull request of current branch with Magit

Tags: magit

It's very common that, after pushing a given branch upstream, I'll want to visit it on github and create a pull request. I'm starting to get annoyed at having to manually visit the repo, find the branch, and create the PR.

**Q:** How can I write a command that visits the PR url in a browser?

The PR url is given by `https://github.com/ORIGIN-REPO/compare/BRANCH-NAME`. Since both the `origin` and the `branch-name` known by Magit (and by plain `git`), it should be easy to write a command that builds that URL and calls `browse-url` on it.

Unfortunately, I know nothing about the internals workings of Magit,
so I don't know how to get that information.

Comment: I haven't explored this, but there's a relevant pull request to a magit plugin: https://github.com/sigma/magit-gh-pulls/pull/21

Comment: @glucas looks promising. I'll test when I get the time.

Comment: Oh, this is useful…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
(defun pull-request-url ()
  "Build the URL or the pull requestion on GitHub corresponding
to the current branch. Uses Magit."
  (interactive)
  (format "%s/compare/%s"
           (replace-regexp-in-string
            (rx (and string-start (1+ any) "github.com:" (group (1+ any)) ".git" string-end))
            "https://github.com/\\1"
            (magit-get "remote" (magit-get-current-remote) "url"))
          (magit-get-current-branch)))
```

`magit.el` is pretty easy to read, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Malabarba has [posted his approach](http://endlessparentheses.com/create-github-prs-from-emacs-with-magit.html) on his blog.

```el
(defun endless/visit-pull-request-url ()
  "Visit the current branch's PR on Github."
  (interactive)
  (browse-url (format "https://github.com/%s/pull/new/%s"
                      (replace-regexp-in-string
                       "\\`.+github\\.com:\\(.+\\)\\.git\\'" "\\1"
                       (magit-get "remote" (magit-get-push-remote) "url"))
                      (magit-get-current-branch))))
```

---

By the way, I intend to add similar functionality (and a lot more ;-) to Magit itself, eventually.

Comment: @Malabarba the export of that snippet went wrong on your blog.

Comment: And do let me know when you add something like that into magit. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [magithub](https://github.com/vermiculus/magithub)?

It doesn't let you view the pull request of the current branch, but it gives you a full list of pull requests which you can visit by pressing `RET`.

[image]

Note this requires [hub 2.2](https://github.com/vermiculus/magithub/issues/44).