# Magit: rebase and push, basic questions

Tags: magit, git

I was learning magit and found this screenshot at [Command to visit Github pull request of current branch with Magit](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3900/command-to-visit-github-pull-request-of-current-branch-with-magit):

[image]

I was wondering why we have Rebase and Push (and not just Push) at the top. What would be the difference in pushing vs rebasing in this instance?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upstream branch and the push-target are configured separately, that is why both values are displayed in the status buffer. These settings can point at the same branch, but for branches such as `master`, they tend to identify the same branch.

See [The Two Remotes](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/The-Two-Remotes.html) to learn about the upstream and the push-target. (The upstream actually can be a local branch, which is why I talked about branches instead of remotes above.)

See [this qa](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19162) for why the term "rebase" is used instead of "upstream".

Comment: Thanks so much. So I understand that when you say "upstream" and "push-target" you are talking about rebase and push. How are these configured separately? I haven't done any configuring. What are the default values and how do I configure them separately?

Comment: The relevant git variables can be set from the "branch" menu. `b u` for the **u**pstream, and `b p` for the **p**ush-target. Unless already configured, these removes can also be set from the fetch, pull and rebase menus. The magit manual has more information about these things (https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Branching.html) and I recommend also reading git documentation and/or tutorials about it.